# Compiling linux source to windows 7 w/ makefile.in

Tags: linux, windows, compiler-construction, mingw, cross-compiling

I have the source for a linux-based program, but trying to run in Win7 environment. I found software called "mingw32" and msys that can compile linux source to win7 using makefile.in (included with source). But I get error "nothing to be done for 'makefile.in'"

Source is available here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/libots/files/libots/ots-0.5.0/ots-0.5.0.tar.gz/download

Makefile.in is below

```
# Makefile.in generated automatically by automake 1.4-p6 from Makefile.am

# Copyright (C) 1994, 1995-8, 1999, 2001 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
# This Makefile.in is free software; the Free Software Foundation
# gives unlimited permission to copy and/or distribute it,
# with or without modifications, as long as this notice is preserved.

[...]
POPT_LIBS = @POPT_LIBS@
POPT_REQUIRED = @POPT_REQUIRED@
RANLIB = @RANLIB@
RC = @RC@
STRIP = @STRIP@
VERSION = @VERSION@
VERSION_INFO = @VERSION_INFO@

[...]    
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libots-1.la

[...]
libots-1.la: $(libots_1_la_OBJECTS) $(libots_1_la_DEPENDENCIES)
    $(LINK) -rpath $(libdir) $(libots_1_la_LDFLAGS) $(libots_1_la_OBJECTS) $(libots_1_la_LIBADD) $(LIBS)

[...]    
# Tell versions [3.59,3.63) of GNU make to not export all variables.
# Otherwise a system limit (for SysV at least) may be exceeded.
.NOEXPORT:
```

Comment: makefile.in is not for that. What you get with `./configure` ?

Answer (score 1):

You need msys to run ./configure

- Call msys.bat
- cd to your e.g. `c:\msys\1.0\src\ots-0.5.0` folder
- run `./configure`

you need also `popt-1.5` . So if you don't have it , you have to download and build it first.

It's not that easy to build with mingw .

I would suggest first of all, download , the binary version for windows. If it runs without problems on your system, you can try to build it yourself. [Ots-0.4.2-Win32-binary.zip](http://libots.sourceforge.net/Ots-0.4.2-Win32-binary.zip)

I doubt that this binary version works without error.

If you have time (3 days will not be enough)
you can download [popt-1.8-1-src.zip](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/files/popt/1.8-1/popt-1.8-1-src.zip/download) .

But you must have also see line : configure:20043: checking for glib-2.0 >= 2.0 libxml-2.0 >= 2.4.23
and more.

Comment: configure:20043: checking for glib-2.0 >= 2.0 libxml-2.0 >= 2.4.23 is not in configure log. I need this program for important project, so time is not a problem. I download popt-1.8.

Comment: what do i need to do next?

Comment: @user2468695 : if `./configure` , has generated the makefiles , you can try a `make` .

Comment: @user2468695 : how far have you come ?

Comment: it's ok, I do not need this anymore. I figured a way from understanding part of the source code.